# GeForce 930Mの刺さったノートpcに CUDA Toolkitをインストールしたい

Tags: cuda, chainer

Windows10で、CUDA Toolkit 7.5をGeForce 930Mの刺さったノートパソコンにインストールしたいのですがうまくいきません。
はたから性能は期待していないのですが、CUDAで動くかどうかだけでも実際に確認できる環境のノートパソコンに作りたいと思っています。
CUDA7.0でもシステムチェックの段階で同様の文言が出てきます。
当方、TheanoとChainerからCUDAを使う予定です。

930MでGPGPUをすることはできないのでしょうか。また、できるのなら導入の方法を教えていただけると有り難いです。
[image: スクショ]

Answer (score 2):

GeForce 930M自体はCUDAに対応しています。

CUDA Toolkitには特定のバージョンの開発者向けグラフィックスドライバーが同梱されていて、高速インストールすると勝手にそのドライバーがインストールされます。NVIDIAのグラフィックスドライバースイートには、CUDA/OpenCLドライバーも含まれています。おそらくCUDA Toolkit 7.5に同梱されているドライバーは、Windows 10とGeForce 930Mの組み合わせに対応したドライバーではないため、当該の警告メッセージが表示されてしまっているものと思われます。

CUDA Toolkit同梱のドライバーでないとCUDAアプリケーションを開発・実行できないということはまったくないので、CUDA Toolkitインストール後にWindows 10向けのGeForce 930M対応ドライバーを改めて上書きインストールしてください。現時点での最新版は下記です。

[365.10 WHQL, Windows 10 64-bit](http://www.nvidia.co.jp/download/driverResults.aspx/102219/jp)
[365.10 WHQL, Windows 10 32-bit](http://www.nvidia.co.jp/download/driverResults.aspx/102237/jp)

Answer (score 1):

ちょうどCUDA Cの第一章を読み終わったところなので答えられます。
アーキテクチャ、コンピュートケイパビリティに[問題は無い](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/notebook-gpus/geforce-930m)です。
しかし、気になるのは[ウィキペディア](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA#.E3.83.8F.E3.83.BC.E3.83.89.E3.82.A6.E3.82.A7.E3.82.A2)の

> モバイル向けの統合型プロセッサでは、Keplerアーキテクチャを採用しているNVIDIA Tegra K1以降となる。実行には専用のデバイスドライバを必要とする。

詳しい[GPUサポート](http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus)の現状です。
以下からドライバーを手に入れて試してみるのはいかがですか？
http://www.geforce.com/drivers
自分はラプトップではないので試すことはできませんが。ご参考までに

Comment: 試してみました。
どうも、CUDAを使うためのものとは違うドライバのようです。
また、これを入れたあとにCUDA Toolkit 7.5をインストールしようとしてみましたが、やはり同じ警告が出ました。

Comment: それ以外のシステム要求です。表を参照してください。http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/index.html#system-requirements

Comment: http://d.hatena.ne.jp/norio515/20111112/1321105385

Answer (score 0):

[NVIDIA の　CUDAのページ](http://www.nvidia.co.jp/object/cuda_learn_products_jp_old.html)

に、対応グラフィックボードの一覧が出ていますが、GeForce 930Mは含まれていないようです。

一覧にあるグラフィックボードを搭載したノートパソコンで試されては如何ですか？